# Где необходимо поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

У меня есть фотография(,) в качестве доказательства.
Я слышу(,) как стучит дятел.
Но(,) когда мальчик показывает это для сестры(,) он становится профессионалом.
Ошибся(,) после того(,) как повернулся в сторону.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу на то, чего в учебнике нет.

1. Возможны варианты: обособление обстоятельства факультативно и зависит **от ситуации.**

*— У вас нет доказательств. — У меня есть фотография в качестве доказАтельства.*

*— Почему вы так решили? — У меня есть **фотогрАфия**,  в качестве доказательства.*

В первом случае обстоятельство входит в основное сообщение, а во втором идет как дополнительное.

2. *Я слышу, **как стучит дятел***.

Обычное СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. Союз КАК здесь изъяснительный (не сравнительный), он используется вместо обычного союза ЧТО и имеет значение **достоверности.**

3. ***Но когда** мальчик показывает это для сестры, он становится профессионалом.*

Обособление присоединительного союза НО факультативно, посмотрите у Розенталя: [Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140).

4. Скорее всего так: *Ошибся **после тогО,** как повернулся в сторону.*

Сравнить: *ОшИбся, после того как повернулся в стОрону.*

Расчленение союза ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК факультативное, авторское, но выбор можно проверить **при расстановке ударений**. В первом варианте придаточное более значимо, чем во втором.

[Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138)